# How to change the color of an individual ellipse when clicking a jButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mouselistener, ellipse

I want to be able to click the JButton and change the next individual ellipse I make to its respective color, Red or Black, from its default Blue. So far I'm able to change the color of all the ellipses I have made.

```
public class MainClient {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainClient window = new MainClient();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public MainClient() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
    private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final SpriteField panel = new SpriteField();
    panel.setBounds(0, 110, 782, 331);
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int tX = e.getX();
            int tY = e.getY();
            panel.CreateObjectAt(tX,tY);
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    final JButton btnRed = new JButton("black");
    btnRed.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            panel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    });
    btnRed.setBounds(229, 500, 97, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnRed);

    JButton btnRed_1 = new JButton("red");
    btnRed_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            panel.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
    btnRed_1.setBounds(342, 500, 97, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnRed_1);

}
```

}

I have a SriteField Class

```
public class SpriteField extends JPanel
{
    ArrayList<RoundSprite>mSprites = new ArrayList<RoundSprite>();

    private Color color = Color.BLUE;
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform tOldTransform = g2.getTransform();

        for(RoundSprite tOne:mSprites)
        {
            tOne.DrawSprite(g2, color);
        }
        g2.setTransform(tOldTransform);
    }
    public void CreateObjectAt(int tX, int tY)
    {
        //make sprite
        RoundSprite mLonely = new RoundSprite();
        //set position
        mLonely.SetPosition(tX, tY);
        //add to array
        mSprites.add(mLonely);
        repaint();
    }
    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        this.color = color;
        repaint();
    }
```

}

I have a RoundSprite Class

```
public class RoundSprite 
{
int mX;
int mY;
private Color color;
void DrawSprite(Graphics2D g2, Color color)
{

    AffineTransform tOldTransform = g2.getTransform();
    g2.setColor(color);
    g2.translate(mX, mY); //got it out from the corner

    g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(-15, -22, 30, 50));

    g2.setTransform(tOldTransform);

}
public void SetPosition(int tX, int tY) //g2.translate
{
    mX = tX;
    mY = tY;        
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 1):

There are three core issues...

## One

In order for the `panel_1` `MouseListener` to change the color of the sprites within `panel`, the `MouseListener` requires a reference to the `panel`.

You could declare the `panel` as `final` within the `initialize` method, but I prefer to make the `panel` a `private` instance field of the `MainClient`.

## Two

In order to change the color, the `SpriteField` needs to provide a means by which interested parties can request a change.

This is going to require `SpriteField` to provide some kind of method that interested parties can call when they need to, for example, a `setColor` method...

```
public class SpriteField extends JPanel {

    private Color color = Color.BLACK;
    //...
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
        repaint();
    }
```

Then `panel_1`'s `MouseListener` can now reference the `SpriteField` and call a method which can produce a change...

```
panel_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Click");
        panel.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
});
```

## Three

You need some way to tell the sprite what color it should be...

This one depends on what it is you want to achieve...

If you want to paint ALL the sprites the same color, then you need some way to tell the sprites which color they should use, for example, you could change the `DrawSprite` method to accept a `Color` parameter...

```
public class RoundSprite {
    //...
    void DrawSprite(Graphics2D g2, Color color) {
```

And within the `SpriteField` `paintComponent`, pass the color to the sprite

```
public class SpriteField extends JPanel {
    //...
    private Color color = Color.BLACK;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform tOldTransform = g2.getTransform();


        for (RoundSprite tOne : mSprites) {
            tOne.DrawSprite(g2, color);
        }
        g2.setTransform(tOldTransform);
    }
```

Now, this will paint ALL the sprites within the field the same color, if you want to change the color of individual sprites, this comes infinitely more complicated...

Lets leave aside the issues of selecting a sprite for the moment...

Basically, you would need to apply the same principle from point **Two** to the `RoundSprite` class.

You would need to supply a method that could `set/get` the desired color.  You would need to store this value in an instance field of the `RoundSprite` class and when `DrawSprite` is called, apply that `Color` to the `Graphics` context.

This would mean that `SpriteField` won't need to perform any color management, beyond passing the request for change from a caller to the selected sprite, so it would still need a `setColor` method...

#### Side Notes...

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Oh, and you realise that there already is a `JButton` class that probably should be used instead of a `JPanel` with a `MouseListener`....?

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is my first post so I tried to write my code as best I could. I have switched to Jbutton and it all worked out. I'm sure I would need to change the color for each individual ellipse because later on I will need to resize and rotate each individual one as well as undo one.

Comment: Then you will need to define a means by which you could select an individual sprite, probably via a `MouseListener` on `SpriteField` which would loop through the `mSprites` list and determine if the mouse "hit" any of the sprites...